# Pass array with all elements zero (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, argument-passing

There is a function:

```
void fnc (T arg[]) {

    // inside the function there is something like this:
    // A = B + arg[index] * C;
}
```

In some situations, there is nothing to pass so, `arg[]` should be zero. So, is there a way to call function as this way: `void fnc(0);`?

Comment: `T * arg` would be clearer in this case.

Comment: passing an array with all elements 0 is not the same as passing a reference to an empty array.

Comment: So, what do you really want - pass array with all elements = 0 or pass empty array?

Answer (score 4):

In that case you can call function will `null` value e.g : `fnc (NULL);` . But make sure to check in function whether `arg == NULL` or not before using it.

P.s: Best thing is to use `std::vector` instead of simple array.

Comment: Did you change the function argument to T* arg and are you really checking for the case arg==NULL?

Comment: @Shibli check this: http://ideone.com/GDUCz, you can pass NULL or 0 ,since NULL is macro defined 0, What compiler you're using?

Comment: @Mr.Anubis: I have checked the link. Compiler is Intel.